# Maze game inputting into a 2D vector

Tags: c++, vector, maze

I am attempting to create a maze that is imported from a file and then placed into a vector that holds a vector of bools.

My problem is that I have taken the info from the file but I am unsure of how to then process it into the 2D vector. In the maze, any coordinate that has a "+" is a path while anything else (blank space, etc) is a wall. The start and finish locations are `Location` objects, but I have not coded that yet.

```
vector<vector<bool> > mazeSpec;
string buffer; //holds lines while they are read in
int length; //holds length of each line/# of columns
Location start, finish;

ifstream mazeFile("maze.txt");
if (!mazeFile) {
    cerr << "Unable to open file\n";
    exit(1);
}

getline(mazeFile, buffer); // read in first line
cout << buffer << endl; //output first line
length = buffer.length(); //length now set so can be compared

while (getline(mazeFile, buffer)) {
    bool path = (buffer == "*");
    cout << buffer << endl;
}
```

Comment: You need to provide a complete mini sample file and the desired resulting 2D array. It's also not clear why you read the first line and store its length for later comparison -- compare it to *what*? You mention `+` in the description yet use `*` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should fill it char by char.
For every line in the file, add a line to mazeSpec:

```
mazeSpec.resize(mazeSpec.size() + 1);
```

For every char you read, add a column to the line of mazeSpec you're working on:

```
mazeSpec[i].push_back(buffer[j] == '*');
```

You'll get something like this:

```
int i, j;
vector<vector<bool> > mazeSpec;
string buffer; //holds lines while they are read in
int length; //holds length of each line/# of columns
Location start, finish;

ifstream mazeFile("maze.txt");
if (!mazeFile) {
    cerr << "Unable to open file\n";
    exit(1);
}

getline(mazeFile, buffer); // read in first line
cout << buffer << endl; //output first line
length = buffer.length(); //length now set so can be compared

mazeSpec.resize(1);
for(j = 0; j < buffer.length(); j++) {
    mazeSpec[0].push_back(buffer[j] == '*');  // or perhaps '+'
}

i = 1;
while (!mazeFile.eof()) {   // read in maze til eof
    getline(mazeFile, buffer);

    mazeSpec.resize(mazeSpec.size() + 1);
    for(j = 0; j < buffer.length(); j++) {
        mazeSpec[i].push_back(buffer[j] == '*');  // or perhaps '+'
    }

     cout << buffer << endl;
     i++;
}
```